# Select values from two tables using “WHERE NOT IN” and DISTINCT in LINQ in Linq to Sql

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have two table like **Customer** and **VisitDetail** and i need to convert below **SQL Query** into **Linq to Sql**

```
select *
from Customer
where id not in (select distinct CustomerId
                 from visitdetail
                 where VisitDate='2016-06-13' and SalesRepAccId=1 and
                       RouteId=10
                ) and
      RouteId = 10 and Active=1 and SalesRepAccId=1
```

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities? to SQL, they're NOT the same!), *and* show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of **[`!Contains()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx)** in case of nested queries for `NOT IN` clause.

```
var customerVisitDetails = (from row in db.Visitdetail
                            where row.VisitDate == '<add obj for date comparison>'
                            && row.SalesRepAccId == 1 && row.RouteId == 10
                            select row.CustomerId).Distinct().ToList();

var output = (from c in db.Customer
              where !customerVisitDetails.Contains(c.Id)
              && c.RouteId == 10 && c.Active == 1 && c.SalesRepAccId == 1
              select c);
```

Also, this is very helpful for [starting with LinQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx)